# How to get a uniform line width in PDF regardless of the device space aspect ratio?

Tags: pdf

The width of a line in PDF is defined in terms of distances in the user space. In my use case, the aspect ratio of the device space (e.g. 4:3) is different from the aspect ratio of the user space (e.g. 1:1), which causes the line widths in the device space to be different in vertical and horizontal directions.

For example, in this picture the horizontal and vertical lines should be of the same width, but they're not:

[image]

I would like to perform scaling that only results in line width uniformity and does not affect anything else.

I asked a similar question regarding PostScript here: [How to ensure line widths are the same vertically and horizontally in PostScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223535/how-to-ensure-line-widths-are-the-same-vertically-and-horizontally-in-postscript). A solution based in part on the answer to this question works for PostScript, but does not work in PDF after what seems to be an almost one-to-one translation.

I tried changing the stroke command `S` to `q 1 0 0 1.5 0 0 cm S Q h`, where `q` saves the graphics state, `1 0 0 1.5 0 0 cm` scales the current transformation matrix, `Q` restores the graphics state, and `h` closes the current subpath. However, in addition to correctly scaling the line widths, this also scales the y-coordinates of the line endpoints by 1.5.

This is what I need to get:

[image]

But with `q 1 0 0 1.5 0 0 cm S Q h`, I get this instead:

[image]

How to make the line width uniform in the device space in PDF without affecting anything else?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you try to achieve. One remark, though, `q 1 0 0 1.5 0 0 cm S Q h` is invalid pdf syntax in multiple ways, **S** must immediately follow a path definition or clip path instruction which **cm** definitively is not, and **h** must be in a path definition which after **Q** is impossible.

Comment: In the first picture, the line width is larger in the horizontal direction than in the vertical direction. This is an unintended effect of the aspect ratio in the device space being different from the aspect ratio in the user space. I am trying to modify the stroke so that the line width is uniform, as in the second picture.

Comment: The paths are defined in the original code right before the `S`s. There are six paths in total, each followed by `S`. How can the line width be made uniform?

Comment: OK. So you want to increase widths in one direction but not lengths. I'm afraid that's not easily doable. Essentially you can scale globally using an asymmetric scaling **cm** at the very beginning and then adapt all coordinates accordingly.